# 92% error rate with Stripe webhooks, unpredictable response

Tags: node.js, server, stripe-payments, webhooks, caddy

I'm setting up Stripe webhooks for the first time. I've made dozens of test requests and I've had an error rate of 92%. It's unpredictable as to why the failures occur.

The failure responses on the dashboard are either:

```sh
Timed out connecting to remote host
```

or

```sh
Failed to connect to remote host
```

My webhook (I've simplified it for testing). 8% of the time, I get a 200 response with `{received: true}`:

```js
expressRouter.route('/hooks').post( async (req, res) => {

  const event = req.body;

  console.log("Event:");
  console.log(event);

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
      // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
      break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
      const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
      // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.json({received: true});
})
```

I have added Stripe's IPs to iptables. I'm running my server with Caddy on Ubuntu 18.04. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your nodejs server constantly rebooting ? what does the log says ?

Comment: Nope, it's been up for hours. The only logs that I'm getting are the 8% of successful events where I get the console.log on the default switch

Comment: Are your first two `log` statements being executed?  Do you consistently see the console.log(event) output?

Comment: try removing all the code from your server / hook. then you will have no errors. and you will be able to add your "bad code" step by step to isolate the failing part

Comment: @RyanM, nope, the logs aren't being executed.

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO, I've tried that, but still nothing. I think the request is not reaching the hook in the first place

Comment: @Joseph it does sound like the requests are not reaching this function.  Best guess is to start looking upstream.  Since you do get 8% success it doesn't sound like a `ufw` issue with Ubuntu but I'm not sure where to go next (unfamiliar with Caddy).